# 404 file not found, even though it 100% exists

Tags: php

I wrote some code that allows people to upload documents, it creates a record in a table and then creates a folder with that index and puts the document in there.

The issue isn't with the upload, because it works for every other file I have uploaded.

The documents get uploaded into the following directory: `uploads/{ID}/{fileName}`

There is a document with the ID `1289` and fileName `Banking cashing up issues.msg`

So when I open it up in browser, it says

> 404 - File or directory not found

How can this be possible? I've checked the directory, and both the folder and file exist with that exact name.

I even have the following script which I put in the `uploads` directory:

```
<?php
function dirToArray($dir) {

    $result = array();

    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
    {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
        {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
            {
                $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            }
            else
            {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

echo json_encode(dirToArray("."));
?>
```

Which gives me lots of entries, one of them being:

```
"1289": [
    "Banking cashing up issues.msg",
    "Mastersheet.xlsx"
  ],
```

Accessing `Mastersheet.xlsx` works, but not for `Banking cashing up issues.msg`.

Comment: you shouldn't have spaces in names... they can cause issues (as in, have you escaped each space before trying to call it)?

Comment: And yet it works for every other document. The browser deals with the spaces by replacing them with `%20`. I don't believe the spaces are the problem, since as I said, it works for other documents with spaces.

Comment: The ones with spaces in? Also, is it a Linux or Windows server?

Comment: I even renamed the file and removed the spaces, same problem. So I don't see why your comment is getting upvoted so much.

Comment: Chill ma dude, no need for hostility -  as asked, what OS are you on? Also, have you checked using the standard DirectoryIterator and just var_dump the contents of the folder to see how the Server parses it?

Comment: The server is on Windows.

Comment: The reason it is highly upvoted comment is because it's a common issue. Can you `var_dump($cdir);`

Comment: Yes, I have done var_dump and it shows the file there with that exact name. Not sure what else to say.